# Reading of text on artwork

Tags: traditional-characters, names, reading

This text/name is from a piece of art, can someone help with the reading please?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

写于古都长安  xie3 yu2 gu3 du1 chang2 an1
（Written in the ancient capital Chang'an)

Well, I believe this art work wrote traditional Chinese: 寫於古都長安